# What is the purpose for the pod throwing you?

Tags: nier-automata

I completed all of the playthroughs in NieR: Automata and when going through the quests that I had missed through chapter select, I accidentally found a new move (R1 + X) where the pod kind of spins you in a circle and then throws you in the direction you are pointing. Is there a purpose for this move (maybe allowing for a longer series of jumps to cross any platforms)? It appears that it is just another way to move.

Comment: With the pod throw, you can clear much longer gaps by double jumping, pod throwing, then dashing. I've used it constantly after discovering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's technically an attack, as I discovered recently. It doesn't do very much damage and it's quite difficult to aim, so it's not very useful. Most weapons can close the gap between you and an enemy pretty well as it is.

Here is a video of me partially attempting an arena with only pod kicks. If it looks like its powerful, it's because these enemies are 19 levels lower. It doesn't actually do much damage.

Comment: Does it knock enemies back or is there another effect when you hit an enemy? Or does it just do a little damage?

Comment: @LostWookie I'd have to check to be sure, but I don't recall it having knockback (but then again, I didn't use this attack hardly at all, so I may be wrong)

Comment: I always found it to be more useful as aerial movement than an attack. Such attack is required at certain points in the game to reach otherwise-inaccessible locations and chests.

Answer (score 1):

There's a side quest in the city that looks like it can only be reached by use of the pod kick mechanic to close the distance.